# Javascript convert float to Exponential

Tags: javascript

I have to convert the float to exponential..

```
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000021
```

Using

```
parseFloat(result)
```

Gives `2.1e-87`

But

```
10000000
```

Gives `10000000` (same)  but I like to get `100.0e+3` etc..So I used `parseFloat(result).toExponential(3);`  But the problem here is it is truncating everything ev even if it has more values for example `111222333` it makes it as `111.22+3` so while I reconverting as integer I am cannot get the original value..

Is there any javascript function to achieve this or how can I achieve this..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi @FelixKling I searched SO for this solution several times but I could not find it.. only then I created this task.. that question does not hit my search parameter itself..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [`toExponential()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential) with out the parameter, it will not drop the fractions:

```
console.log( (111222333).toExponential() ); // "1.11222333e+8"
```

The parameter specifies the amount of digits after the decimal point. If you drop it, it displays as many digits as needed (wrt to the double precision JavaScript uses internally).

Comment: your comment should be `"1.11222333e+8"`

Comment: Thank you so much.. i works good.. and now I am getting as you suggested.. thank you once again..